# Avro schema evolution: extending an existing array

Tags: hadoop, avro

Standard Avro schema evolution examples show adding a new field with a default value to a record. But what if your old schema had an array and you want to add a new field to that array?

For example, given an array of records:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "name": "Loss",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "lossTotalAmount",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "lossType",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "lossId",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "vehicleLossCode",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding a new field `claimNumber`:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "name": "Loss",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "lossTotalAmount",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "lossType",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "lossId",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "vehicleLossCode",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "claimNumber",
        "type": [ "null", "string" ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using the regular technique doesn't seem to work as I start running into deserialization exceptions. Is there a different way to extend existing arrays in Avro or is it impossible?

Comment: Both schemas look compatible according to Avro's evolution rules; are you specifying both the reader's and writer's schemas explicitly when deserializing?

Comment: Can you provide with the deserializing code or the deserialization exceptions that you get?